(US) San Francisco: worst that can happen if you enter a shop and start eating?
I'm sick and tired of having to spend 25 hours a day just to get change for sufficient food, and to go without for months consecutive.
Assuming, if provided a DA does not prosecute—What's the absolute worst that can happen, de facto, if you enter a [minimart / Safeway / Trader Joes / Walgreens etc] shop and just proceed eating and drinking what you need?
For example, opening a box of granola bars, not putting one into your pocket but unwrapping it and start eating. For example, unscrewing the cap of a bottle and pouring it, not towards the floor but the mouth (btw I can finish one of those half-litre ones well under 7 secs). Etc.
(I'm aware of the existence of trigger-happy guards, but this question ignores the unlucky cases where you get shot.)

Related (not sure if it is a duplicate or not): https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/96162/what-is-the-legal-status-of-shoplifting-in-san-francisco/96170#96170

You would probably be arrested and prosecuted for a misdemeanor offense called "shoplifting," punishable by up to 6 months in county jail. The assumption of the question that you would not be prosecuted at all by the DA is an unreasonable one, even though the DA in San Francisco may not take shoplifting particularly seriously.
The current San Francisco DA diverts cases to mental health treatment and substance abuse treatment in cases where those are viable options, but nothing in the question indicates that this is true in this case.
The actual punishment is more likely to be a few days in jail, followed by a guilty plea to time served sentence, accompanied by a criminal fine greater than the price of the food taken.
A better course of action would be to go to the county welfare office and apply for benefits, as you are almost surely eligible for at least some benefits.

@Jen The issue of shoplifting in San Francisco is a contentious one politically, with many accusing the San Francisco DA of doing little to stop it and deprioritizing it. See, e.g.https://www.sfgate.com/politics/article/Chesa-Boudin-retail-theft-data-17005912.php The current DA makes heavy "use of diversion programs, which re-route suspected offenders to mental health and substance abuse programs, rather than incarceration. . . . After Boudin took office in 2020, the diversion rate for petty theft reached a record high of 63.6%, while the conviction rate reached a record low of 7.3%.")

@Jen this is contentious because some people would rather see someone punished than see someone try to fix the underlying problems.

Would you only be arrested if you tried to leave the store without paying?  I see people in the local supermarket eating things while they push their cart around.  I assume that they scan the empty wrapper when they are checking out.

I can imagine an indigent person being OK with being arrested for this. They feed you in jail, don't they?

@PeterM "I assume that they scan the empty wrapper when they are checking out." They do. This is common practice in some grocery stores. Of course, there there is this: https://www.reddit.com/r/thatHappened/comments/qfnbz0/local_woman_drinks_laundry_detergent_at_walmart/

@DaleM, your comment presents a false dichotomy.  Administering normal punishment for breaking the law shouldn't be "contentious", and addressing the underlying root cause or motive isn't mutually exclusive.

@MichaelHall not at all “normal punishment” is often contentious- the death penalty or caning for example. It also doesn’t present a dichotomy either, you can do both- it’s just that some people want to do one and not the other.

A security guard beats you to death.
You said to disregard the case where a security guard shoots you to death, but the incident you linked to involved the fatal gun violence occurring only after the security guard grappled with the shoplifter.
It's entirely possible that a physical confrontation of this kind where a security guard attempts to physically restrain you from continuing to consume the food could potentially result in fatal injuries, even without firearms becoming involved.
"I can't breathe" became a rallying cry for the Black Lives Matter movement following the death of George Floyd for a reason, after all, and no firearms were involved in that particular incident.

Certainly worse than the situation where the company sues you in a civil court and your benefits are docked $1 a week till damages and costs are paid off (precise methods of getting your money may vary).

While police enjoy a great amount of immunity, both de jure and de facto, I doubt a security guard can get away with the same defense. Beating a man (even if not to death) for taking a few candy bars is some "Les Miserables" level overreaction.

@Barmar I mean, it actually happened in the incident linked in the OP. If things had gone a bit more poorly it's possible that the criminal that got shot to death by a security guard could have struck their head on the floor and dies from the resulting brain injury during their initial tussle with the security guard.
